# Pass Docker ENV variable to rails app

Tags: bash, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, environment-variables

I am testing a rails app utilizing a docker container. What I am trying to do is pass an `ENV` variable at run using the `-e` flag like so:
 `docker run -p 3000:3000 -d -e "DOCKER_HOST=$(ip -4 addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')" somerepo/image:tag`. This works I know because when I bash into the container and run `env` I get the correct variable set:

```
$ env
HOSTNAME=1641e2f6c81f
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
DOCKER_HOST=172.17.0.1
...
```

When I try to set this in `mongoid.yml` in the rails app like so:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: somerailsdb
      hosts:
        - ${DOCKER_HOST}:27017
      options:
  options:
```

I get the following mongodb error when I try to fetch database records:

`App 10040 stdout: D, [2016-01-10T11:40:07.085516 #10040] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

This tell me that the value is not being set in the app. How do I pass this correctly in the `mongoid.yml` config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to use environment variable values in `mongoid.yml` is:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: somerailsdb
      hosts:
        - <%= ENV['DOCKER_HOST'] %>:27017
      options:
  options:
```